# how to change xls file with java poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I made a function that writes a file .xls with poi:

```
    public void write() throws IOException{
    String excelFileName = "C:\\Users/Default/Desktop/MyFirstExcel.xls";//name of excel file

    String sheetName = "Sheet1";//name of sheet

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName) ;

    //iterating r number of rows
    for (int r=0;r <10; r++ )
    {
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);

        //iterating c number of columns
        for (int c=0;c < 5; c++ )
        {
            HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);

            cell.setCellValue((String)"Cell "+r+" "+c); //+r+" "+c
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);

    //write this workbook to an Outputstream.
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Done");
            alert.showAndWait();                   
}
```

This method creates a new file each time, and I was wondering how to append information into the file.
I tried to cange this line:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName,true);
```

This does not seem enough.

Comment: you need to open and modify the workbook if you wanna change the excel

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the Workbook object from the file/inputstream, then you can read the existing Rows/Cells/... and modify/add to the content i.e.

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(excelFileName);
try {
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
    ...
    // write to a new file here!
    wb.write(outStream);
} finally {
    stream.close();
}
```

See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#HSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream)